# Cant get time stamps for posts to stay posted correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to time stamp posts that people make on my simple blog website. I just want the timestamp to be at the bottom of their posts. I have it working now, however once I make a new posts, all the time stamps for recent posts update to the new posts timestamp. Not sure how to go about fixing this tho, I tried different php time stamps, etc but still no go. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Here is my PHP

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="post.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Your Daily Dorm News Post! </h1>
<div id="container"> <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php if ( isset($_GET['message']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['message']) ) {

    echo $_GET['message'];

} else {

    echo "The message is not valid! The message box was blank or you entered invalid symbols!\n";

}
?>

This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>


</div>
<?php 
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php 
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
 * Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
 */ 

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);

$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
  // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']); 
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  
  // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
  $post_fields = array();
  $post_fields['name'] = $name;
  $post_fields['email'] = $email;
  $post_fields['message'] = $message;
  $post_fields['date'] = $date;
  $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);

}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

require('header.php');
?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New York'); $date_posted = date('h:i:s Y-m-d'); ?>
    <p><a href="form.php">Submit a Post</a></p>

    <?php
    if(isset($name)) {
      echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
    }
    ?>

    <p>Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
    <ul id="posts_list">
    <div id="posts">
    <?php 

    // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
    $counter = 1;

    foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
      $name = $post['name'];
      $email = $post['email'];
      $message = $post['message'];
      $date = $post['date'];

      if ($counter % 2==1)
        $li_class = "float-left";
      else
        $li_class = "float-right";

      echo '<div class=post>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This evemt occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';
  echo $date_posted;
  echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');


  echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show `saveCurrentPost()` method code

Comment: This is the savecurrentpost thing // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
  $post_fields = array();
  $post_fields['name'] = $name;
  $post_fields['email'] = $email;
  $post_fields['message'] = $message;
  $post_fields['date'] = $date;
  $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);
.  I also have my posts.dat file, but that is just where the information is saved, its blank now

Answer (score 0):

The date function defaults to the current timestamp unless overriden.

```
//echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime( $date ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving the date function the date that's on the post. If you don't supply the date that's on the post as a second parameter then it will just print today's date every time. If your date isn't stored as time you need to convert it using strtotime() first.

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: ok so just replace what I had with this? since i forgot strtotime?

Comment: I tried this, but its giving this as a date. Friday 22nd of November 2013 12:00:00 AM Seems like its off

Comment: you're not passing your date function the date on the post, so yes you need to change it to pass the post's date

Comment: Then you probably need to use something to the affect of `date_default_timezone_set('America/New York');` if it's off, depending on your timezone @Terry

Comment: how would I do that? I just need it to time stamp the post, and not be overridden. I'll see what I can do

Comment: seems like its grabbing the $date from the date that the user entered for when the event occurred, instead of what I want

Comment: First assign it using `<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New York'); $date_posted = date('h:i:s Y-m-d'); ?>`  then use `echo $date_posted;` where you now have `date_default_timezone_set('EST');` @Terry you will need to read up on the `date()` function to get it the way you want it to show. You need to be resourceful here. That's one way of doing it. The other is using a relational table in DB using the `NOW()` function.

Comment: What blogging software are you using? Wordpress?

Comment: like so?     echo '<div class=post>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This evemt occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';
  echo $date_posted;
date_default_timezone_set('America/New York'); $date_posted = date('h:i:s Y-m-d');
  
  echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>

Comment: No, assign it first outside of your HTML. Do it exactly as I posted above. @Terry

Comment: oh, wait im confused. so put the first string of code in the form file or the posting_wall.php file?

Comment: Here try this pastebin file. It's only good for 10 minutes, so get it now **http://pastebin.com/Vi6SxGC1** @Terry

Comment: Here is a photo to show whats happening, see how all the dates are the same? being overridden http://i44.tinypic.com/j6u428.jpg

Comment: Ok just saw your edit. Did you try it and do look at my pastebin file too. @Terry I think your edit should theoretically work.

Comment: Tried it, still the dates are being overridden, they all change to the new post date when a new post is made,

Comment: yea i replaced my entire file with your pastebin file,

Comment: Ok I know what's going on. Any way you can set up a DB instead? @Terry

Comment: db? dropbox? sure I can upload it all to a dropbox, will do now

Comment: I'm going to have to get back to you on that, head's gone to mush right now. However, I think that your posts' timestamps may need to be stored inside another table. @Terry there's probably another way to do this, but I can't wrap my head around it right now.

Comment: ah ok, if ya do find out just email me horgantm@gmail.com ok? I'll keep trying but not really sure either

Comment: Did you happen to fix your problem? I noticed your other questions and thought you have. Include the `at-@` sign followed by my name to notify me. I can't keep checking this post without notification. @Terry

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)